# Example of a Function that is Both Continuous and Uniformly Continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a countable closed subset and let $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$. Is it always possible to produce such a function $f$ that is both continuous and uniformly continuous?

Comment: Do you agree that $f(s)=0$ for all $s \in S$ defines a function with these properties? You are required to make an attempt to answer the question yourself before asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to original question:

No. If $S$ is also bounded, then it is compact, and a continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous.

Answer to new question:

Yes. Just take a constant function on S.

Comment: My apologies, I'm an idiot and phrased my question backwards.

Answer (score 0):

First notice that every uniformly continuous function is always continuous, so that part is redundant in your question.

**HINT** Consider a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}.$

**ANSWER**
Next let $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a some function. Let $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta=0.5.$ Then for all $|x-y|<\delta,$ $x,y\in\mathbb{N},$ we have that $|f(x)-f(y)|=0<\epsilon.$ (Why?) So $f$ is uniformly continuous.